# Windows-Server-2012-R2 vhd image cannot be accessed in azure

Tags: powershell, azure

When I am trying to create VM in azure it shows error as

> New-AzureVM: Forbidden Error: You don't have permission to use this image.

I am using this image **a699494373c04fc0bc8f2bb1389d6106__Windows-Server-2012-R2-20150726-en.us-127GB.vhd** for creating VM in azure. Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to use a VM image that you do not have access to. I would suggest running the below PowerShell command to have a look in the Azure VM image store for VHD images you do have access to

```
Get-AzureVMImage |
Where-Object {($_.Label -ne $null) -and ($_.Label.Contains('2012 R2')) 
-and ($_.PublisherName.Contains("Microsoft Windows Server Group"))}
```